# Remove http(s):// in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, xslt-1.0

I'm working on a CMS function where a user could add Meta Data to images.
The Option source is used to create a backlink to the original ressource/main page.

This case works finde to determine, a Link should displayed or just the resource.

But I have problems removing the `http(s)://` from the `a href` link, as this doesn't look good (the link ist stored in `$image_source)`.

Sadly, XSLT 1.0 doesn't support the `replace()` method.

Is there any simple workaround for this? Otherwise the option I have would be a bigger template with `substring-after()`.

```
  <xsl:if test="$image_source!=''">
   <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="starts-with($image_source, 'http://') or starts-with($image_source ,'https://')">
           <span class="image-meta-source">
              <a href="{$image_source}" title="{$image_title}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$image_source"/>
              </a>
            </span>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
        <span class="image-meta-source"><xsl:value-of select="$image_source"/></span>
   </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

Usually, I'd use RegEx here but afaik this isn't supported (like a lot of useful features) in XSLT 1.0. A regular expression I could think about would be `^(http|https)://` Is there a chance to use this, though?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `substring-after($image_source, '//')` perhaps?

Comment: @TimC Yup, see the answoer of michael. I really don't know why I tried to make this complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with($image_source, 'http://') or starts-with($image_source ,'https://')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($image_source, '://')"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: You Sir, are a genius and I'm an idiot :D Thank you very much, I never thought of such a simple solution

Comment: Easy solution to a very common problem. Thanks a lot! Note that you have to use `<xsl:if>` outside of `<xsl:choose>` statements, though.

Comment: No, you don't.    .